# Send AJAX data to Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ajax

Unable to send data to Node.js from my HTML/AJAX, I have variable selectValue which I want to send to my Node server. While making use of data: `{ selectValue: selectValue}` does not help.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectDetails');       
    var selectValue='';
        $.ajax({
                 url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route1",
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType:'json', 

                 success: function(res) {
                     console.log(res);
                     console.log(res.content);
                     $.each(res.content, function(key,value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = new Option(value.hostname+":"+value.port);
                    });
                    $("#myButton").click(function(){
                        var selectValue = document.getElementById("selectDetails").value;
                        console.log(selectValue);
                    });
                },
                data: { selectValue: selectValue}
            });   
        });                          
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
router.post('/route1', function(req, res){ 
    var selValue= req.body.selectValue;
    console.log("Select Value"+selValue);
});
```

`console.log("Select Value"+selValue);` give an undefined value. How do I send the value of selectValue to my node server.

Comment: What do you use for router in app.js?

Comment: An express router object `var router = express.Router(); `

Comment: That works for me. Are you using bodyparser? Do you see the post in browser devtools?

Comment: `var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: If i `console.log(selectValue)` i do see the value in the browser but the same is not being reflected on my node server irrespective of get/post call

Comment: Same node code for me, when testing on node + sending post with Postman app. Maybe typo and missing /api from path?

Comment: I mean if you open your devtools and use the network tab to see the actual network traffic; do you see the post call on network tab?

Comment: That should be working. Probably something like wrong port, wrong url, or having a browser tap open on a server not on localhost.

Comment: Adding the network tab details (refer updated question)

Comment: What does it show if you select the last one:  monitor / XHR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudocode, you need to do something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

      $.ajax("http://localhost:5000/config", function (data) {
         // Get initial values
         // Render values to Select options

      }) 

      $("#myButton").click(function () {
        // get selected value on click
        var selectedValue = 'foo'
        $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:5000/setServer",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { selectedValue: selectValue },
          success: function (res) {
            // on success, do what you need to do after data to server has been set.

          },
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: let me give it a try

Answer (score 0):

This should be moved out of of the post / XHR callback:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
    var selectValue = document.getElementById("selectDetails").value;
    console.log(selectValue);
});
```

Now you are sending empty string ''; to the server, and editing the value of another variable called 'selectValue' inside call handler. The inner selectValue variable shadows the original value, but the orginal value will never be changed.

something like this could work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('selectDetails');       
    var selectValue='foo';

     $("#myButton").click(function(){
         // NO VAR HERE, TO NOT SHADOW THE OUTER VARIABLE
         selectValue = document.getElementById("selectDetails").value;
         console.log('1', selectValue);
         $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8070/api/route1",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType:'json', 
            data: {selectValue: selectValue},
            success: function(res) {
               console.log(res);
              console.log(res.content);
            }
         });  
     });

</script>
```

Comment: so where exactly do I put it?

Comment: Now things were happenign in this order:
1. Set outer 'selectValue' = '';
2. Send post with selectValue: '';
3. After post return success : Attach click handler to button
4. After user clicks the button: Define and set another variable also called ' selectValue', but with scope inside clickhandler function. Set value to whatever was in the text input.

Comment: Okay so I have followed all the steps but now I don't see my `<select>` options like before. let me update the code again

Comment: Could you pls look at it now?

Comment: The `<select>` options are now only visible if I click the button :P. The value is now being sent to node sever. Everything seems to works except i don't see the select options on page load.

Comment: Yeah, left out some lines that were not essential for the POST request to be send.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? You should now be getting {selectValue:'foo'} on your node. Can you explain step by step what should be happening.

Comment: Yes sure. I am getting `localhost:27020` as selectValue's value. Everything is working pretty much fine except my <select> options are not visible on page load. Let me put up some images on my question for better understanding

Comment: Ok , so the problem seems not to be node but front-end and timing and combining DOM manipulation with server calls?

Answer (score 0):

note that your url is: "http://localhost:8070/api/monitor"
and in your app.js file you're trying to post to /route1

Comment: Yeah I kept a dummy route before posting it here, it is pointing to /monitor in both index and app